# Issue with hash of hash in perl

Tags: perl, hash

Can someone please help me with the below code.

```
sub test
  { 
    %hs=@_;
    print %hs;
    print "\n";
    print $hs{'c'}."\n";
    print $hs{'d'}."\n";
    # print "\n";
    print $hs{'e'}{'game'}; # Not getting the output for this step. it should be 12 ? 
    print "\n";
    #print ${$hs{'e'}}{'dv'};
      foreach $key (sort keys %hs)
        {
          print $key."\n";
        }
    }


%hash=('game'=>'12','gh'=>'31');

print $hash{'game'}."\n";

test(c=>'123',d=>'345',e=>"%hash");
```

### output

```
12
e%hashc123d345
123
345

c
d
e
Press any key to continue . . .
```

`print $hs{'e'}{'game'}` is giving me null. Please tell me how to access the hash of the hash.

thanks is advance.

Regards,
Sujeet

Comment: Are you sure that you are generating a hash of hashes ?

Comment: I need this code to work. I dont know whats wrong I am doing. Can you please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should **always** `use strict` and `use warnings` in all your Perl programs. Turning them on showed me this error (after declaring variables using `my`).

> Can't use string ("%hash") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use

The line in question is exactly the one you were thinking.

> ```
> print $hs{'e'}{'game'};
> ```

But now it's easy to spot.

> ```
> test( c => '123', d => '345', e => "%hash" );
> ```

You are trying to interpolate the variable `%hash` somehow. Or maybe you just thought that's how you make a more-dimensional data structure.

To put a hash into a hash, you need to use a *reference* in Perl. You can create a reference your `%hash` by using the `\` reference operator.

```
test( c => '123', d => '345', e => \%hash );
```

Let's try. I've removed the code that's not relevant.

```
sub test {
    my %hs = @_;

    print $hs{'e'}{'game'};
}

my %hash = ( 'game' => '12', 'gh' => '31' );
test( c => '123', d => '345', e => \%hash );
```

And now your output is:

```
12
```

---

To learn more about references in Perl, look at [perlref][2] and [perlreftut][3]. You can also look at these tutorials on Perlmaven:

- https://perlmaven.com/multi-dimensional-arrays-in-perl
- https://perlmaven.com/multi-dimensional-hashes

---

<sup>This is also one of the reasons why I prefer to use the `->` dereferencing operator all the time, so `$hs{e}{game}` becomes `$hs{e}->{game}` although there is no need to do that. Perl will know what you mean. But with the `->` it's more obvious that there is a reference.</sup>

<sup>Also note that hashes do not interpolate, so `"%hash"` does not get expanded using `$,` like `"@array"` would. This might be because hashes are not ordered. Or because you could not do `printf "%s\n"` if they were.</sup>